# Add Url as a varible in js "window.location" not working

Tags: javascript, php, onclick

```
onclick="window.location = 'index.php'"
```

If this is working fine, why is the following code not working?

```
<?php  $link = 'index.php'; ?>

<script>
  var link='<?php echo $link; ?>';
  onclick="window.location = link"
</script>
```

Comment: What is _not working_?  What do you get in source code?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `onclick` on what?

```
<script>
  var link='<?php echo $link; ?>';
  onclick="window.location = link"
</script>
```

Define the onclick listener: (for eg. in `document`)

```
<script>
  var link='<?php echo $link; ?>';
  document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.location = link
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

By clicking the button, the clickHandler() function is invoked which causes the window.location to be set to index.php and the index.php page opens.

```
 <?php  $link = 'index.php'; ?>

 <script>
 function clickHandler() {
    var link='<?php echo $link; ?>';
    window.location = link;
 }
 </script>

<button type="button" onclick="clickHandler()">Click</button>
```